# Making form corresponding to createview accesible only when user is logged in

Tags: django, django-views

I have the following model of an item:

```
#models.py
class Item(models.Model):
    seller = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
```

To make a new item, I have a form located at www.mysite.com/new-item. The currently logged in user will be automatically set as the seller of the item so does not show up in the form.

```
#forms.py
class ItemCreationForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Item
         fields = ['name',]
```

Here is the corresponding view.

```
#views.py
class AddNewItem(CreateView):
    model = Item
    form_class = ItemCreationForm
    template_name = 'add_listing.html'
    success_url = '/listings/'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        item = form.save(commit=False)
        #if not self.request.user.is_anonymous and self.request.user.is_email_verified:
            item.seller = self.request.user
        #else:
        #    return redirect('accounts/login/')
        item.save()
    return super(AddNewListing, self).form_valid(form)
```

The commented out lines are what I'm having trouble with. I'd like the user to be able to access www.mysite.com/new-item only if he is logged in. If he isn't, I would like him to be redirected to a sign up page. Right now, I can get to the form regardless of whether I am registered or not, and am only redirected away from this page when pressing the submit button on the form. I also tried putting the @login_required decorator above the form_valid method, but that didn't work.

Could anyone provide me with some suggestions on what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With some playing around I finally got this working by using a mixin.

```
class AddNewItem(LoginRequiredMixin, CreateView):
        model = Item
        form_class = ItemCreationForm
        login_url = "/signup/"

 ....
```

Much easier than I thought!